# Match Characters Between #s

Tags: regex

If I have some text and then a series of hashtags `xyz #abc1 def #hij #lmn` I'd like to match all text and numbers, apart from trailing whitespace characters after the hashtags so the result should be:

abc1 def
hij
lmn

I've been experimenting with this but the closest I've got is `#[a-zA-Z]*`, which doesn't seem that close...

Comment: Why not replace the `#` with the empty string `''` ? see: https://regex101.com/r/I6aaR8/1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but here will be other text before the `#`

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question....

Comment: @Luuk I should! Just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#[^#]*[^#\s]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lmH9Ga/1). *Details*:

- `#` - a `#` char
- `[^#]*` - zero or more chars other than `#`
- `[^#\s]` - a char other than `#` and whitespace.

To get the part of the match after `#`, either capture that part:

```
#([^#]*[^#\s])
```

and grab Group 1 value, or use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=#)[^#]*[^#\s]
```

In PCRE or Boost, you can even use `\K` operator:

```
#\K[^#]*[^#\s]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to exclude the hashtags though, sorry, should have been more explicit

Comment: Then you can turn that into a positive lookbehind: `(?<=#)[^#]*[^#\s]`

Comment: @AlexS I added three more versions.